# Why my AES 256 decrypt method not working iOS 14

Tags: json, objective-c, encryption, aes, ios14

I'm trying to decrypt a string value from JSON using AES 256 method after get the backend response, each value are parsing properly but when I try decrypt the string value encrypted, my method always return null, the JSON response is:

```
dataResponseString: {
"subjects": [
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "version": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-05-12T03:15:12.741Z",
        "createdBy": "dmostajo",
        "subject": "WLSdQGDlb2CbBtKoK/ukbYv1HOl5ZVZo9P5VRV9426GMurhKD5o7U53MfvYaLmogJCYz32s8uz4B0HxBawlph3sgfdDieA3Lxh8D4WLLXqwY2psVasukKV1HTR9Jst1cI3O/vorvheSRvBb4JZQYotmhVPsjEkSc2xJ5ewyBCL0uv3VRWwe4qhB94Q1F/EowW5s3aH9CRlf/H9hJg1ougyX1ZL02OydMrFMXCwZSALHKLT6kCase/oHTTGyuDvs8xzLk3QSBiUO2G9ppeXmRxYB/sPAFpDI8eV2T5/O+xlIP/LLE/eyKe+wEfxWlKG1uAwiVhfrHmFMueRG7Hv6DJ/s63M2o3vziB6zfX832rQc="
    },
    {
        "name": "test2",
        "version": 1,
        "createdAt": "2021-04-15T16:16:35.206Z",
        "createdBy": "dmostajo",
        "subject": "WLSdQGDlb2CbBtKoK/ukbc1429tOxdpzEE6W/leNEoWJCIzf+R7D6u+FSu1JDXgIGiF5pgh5BJQK3yNJVYxLYsaL3kpP2yL2ALPILY6WdWBA/GJFo3s6Y0rMeEh4UBkb/yDNqbZhK2hrn3e+zvFQYG6i0+rE3rhXkTlRcRWmXB0JRTg7pTt2BtNOe+CynG3SgwowYv+R/244Ab6z/Tg+ejKs41wrKCJcBsiU5Yl18oUCeiycmQYtgRoX+yz2o5X1F/arIDi2pdCBIIS1n7sII+woRL2C0o9N5YJl3zzWnF0RwxmkSPKz7j71+sHO4OIGw+tiaKPDTfQf3K0ViQezEVHO9jAxPglkcEtMm5T1A/dWSTZQv4HjAwQ8ZjmZ5Y25Qki7oQgNStyKPxHafINj8g=="
    }
]
```

}

and whole code that I'm using is:

- To get response from backend:

```
-(void)getSubjects
{
    NSLog(@"Decoding AccessToken:%@",[JWTDecoder decodeJWTToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"access_token"]]);
    NSString *strAuthHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"access_token"]];
    NSDictionary *authHeaders = @{ @"authorization": strAuthHeader };
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myclientservertest/api/v2/subjects"]              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
        timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:authHeaders];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *responseAuth, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            ^{
                [NLCCommonViewController showAlert:ERR_NETWORK];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *dataResponseString= [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"responseAuth:%@",responseAuth);
            NSLog(@"dataResponseString:%@",dataResponseString);
            if([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)responseAuth statusCode] == 200)
            {
                NSError *errorJson;
//                NSData *data = [dataResponseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSDictionary *json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
                NSMutableArray *subjects = [json objectForKey:@"subjects"];
                for (NSMutableDictionary * dict in subjects)
                {
                    NSString *appName = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
                    NSString *version = [dict valueForKey:@"version"];
                    NSString *createdAt = [dict valueForKey:@"createdAt"];
                    NSString *createdBy = [dict valueForKey:@"createdBy"];
                    NSString *subject = [dict valueForKey:@"subject"];
                    NSLog(@"subject:%@",subject);
                    NSString *secret =[self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:CLIENT_VALUE",createdBy]];
                    NSData *subjectData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:subject options:0];
                    NSString *decrypted = [CustomAESHelper decryptData:subjectData withKey:secret];
                    NSLog(@"decrypted:%@",decrypted);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                
            }
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

- The md5 method is working properly:

```
- (NSString*)md5:(NSString*)str {
    NSString *salt = @"";
    NSString *strWithSalt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",str,salt];
    const char *cStr = [strWithSalt UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG) strlen(cStr), result );
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
             result[0], result[1],
             result[2], result[3],
             result[4], result[5],
             result[6], result[7],
             result[8], result[9],
             result[10], result[11],
             result[12], result[13],
             result[14], result[15]
             ] lowercaseString];
}
```

- The AES Helper:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@interface CustomAESHelper : UIViewController

+ (NSString*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key;
+ (NSString*) encryptNSMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArray withKey:(NSString *)key;
+ (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key;

@end
```

```
#import "CustomAESHelper.h"
@implementation NSData (AESAdditions)
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
    
    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    
    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    
    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end

@interface CustomAESHelper ()

@end

@implementation CustomAESHelper
+ (NSString*) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
     NSData *JSONData =  [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
    
    // Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
    NSString *base64Encoded = [JSONData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
//    NSLog(@"encryptString = %@",base64Encoded);
//    NSLog(@"encryptString = %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData
//                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
//    
//    
// NSLog(@"decryptData = %@",[self decryptData:JSONData withKey:key]);
  return base64Encoded;
    
}

+ (NSString*) encryptNSMutableArray:(NSMutableArray *)mutableArray withKey:(NSString *)key
{
    NSData *data = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutableArray]AES256EncryptWithKey:key];
   
   // Get NSString from NSData object in Base64
   NSString *base64Encoded = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
//    NSLog(@"encryptString = %@",base64Encoded);
//    NSLog(@"encryptString = %@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData
//                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
//
//
// NSLog(@"decryptData = %@",[self decryptData:JSONData withKey:key]);
 return base64Encoded;
}

+ (NSString*) decryptData:(NSData*)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[ciphertext AES256DecryptWithKey:key]
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
}

@end
```

- And Logs shows:

```
2021-05-14 12:13:06.806259-0400 MyProjects[1609:814424] subject:WLSdQGDlb2CbBtKoK/ukbYv1HOl5ZVZo9P5VRV9426GMurhKD5o7U53MfvYaLmogJCYz32s8uz4B0HxBawlph3sgfdDieA3Lxh8D4WLLXqwY2psVasukKV1HTR9Jst1cI3O/vorvheSRvBb4JZQYotmhVPsjEkSc2xJ5ewyBCL0uv3VRWwe4qhB94Q1F/EowW5s3aH9CRlf/H9hJg1ougyX1ZL02OydMrFMXCwZSALHKLT6kCase/oHTTGyuDvs8xzLk3QSBiUO2G9ppeXmRxYB/sPAFpDI8eV2T5/O+xlIP/LLE/eyKe+wEfxWlKG1uAwiVhfrHmFMueRG7Hv6DJ/s63M2o3vziB6zfX832rQc=
2021-05-14 12:13:06.809211-0400 MyProjects[1609:814424] decrypted:(null)
2021-05-14 12:13:06.809757-0400 MyProjects[1609:814424] subject:WLSdQGDlb2CbBtKoK/ukbc1429tOxdpzEE6W/leNEoWJCIzf+R7D6u+FSu1JDXgIGiF5pgh5BJQK3yNJVYxLYsaL3kpP2yL2ALPILY6WdWBA/GJFo3s6Y0rMeEh4UBkb/yDNqbZhK2hrn3e+zvFQYG6i0+rE3rhXkTlRcRWmXB0JRTg7pTt2BtNOe+CynG3SgwowYv+R/244Ab6z/Tg+ejKs41wrKCJcBsiU5Yl18oUCeiycmQYtgRoX+yz2o5X1F/arIDi2pdCBIIS1n7sII+woRL2C0o9N5YJl3zzWnF0RwxmkSPKz7j71+sHO4OIGw+tiaKPDTfQf3K0ViQezEVHO9jAxPglkcEtMm5T1A/dWSTZQv4HjAwQ8ZjmZ5Y25Qki7oQgNStyKPxHafINj8g==
2021-05-14 12:13:06.811011-0400 MyProjects[1609:814424] decrypted:(null)
```

Is the first time that I'm working with this method encryption, the encrypt method working properly too, the strange issue that I have is on decrypt method, or am I doing some wrong missing some detail or something, I saw many answers and questions, or how can I convert the string value from JSON to NSData as cypher data properly? or which are your recommendations please, thanks!

UPDATE 1:

Reviewing, when I copy the subject string directly to decrypt without parsing the decrypt method are working properly:

```
NSString *test = @"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";
NSData *dataTest = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:test options:kNilOptions];
NSLog(@"dataTest: %@", dataTest);
NSString *decryptTest = [CustomAESHelper decryptData:dataTest withKey:secret];
NSLog(@"decryptTest: %@", decryptTest);
```

```
2021-05-15 20:33:05.424858-0400 MyProjects[2003:1228662] subject:WLSdQGDlb2CbBtKoK/ukbc1429tOxdpzEE6W/leNEoWJCIzf+R7D6u+FSu1JDXgIGiF5pgh5BJQK3yNJVYxLYsaL3kpP2yL2ALPILY6WdWBA/GJFo3s6Y0rMeEh4UBkb/yDNqbZhK2hrn3e+zvFQYG6i0+rE3rhXkTlRcRWmXB0JRTg7pTt2BtNOe+CynG3SgwowYv+R/244Ab6z/Tg+ejKs41wrKCJcBsiU5Yl18oUCeiycmQYtgRoX+yz2o5X1F/arIDi2pdCBIIS1n7sII+woRL2C0o9N5YJl3zzWnF0RwxmkSPKz7j71+sHO4OIGw+tiaKPDTfQf3K0ViQezEVHO9jAxPglkcEtMm5T1A/dWSTZQv4HjAwQ8ZjmZ5Y25Qki7oQgNStyKPxHafINj8g==
2021-05-15 20:33:05.425797-0400 MyProjects[2003:1228662] dataSubject: {length = 304, bytes = 0x58b49d40 60e56f60 9b06d2a8 2bfba46d ... 8a3f11da 7c8363f2 }
2021-05-15 20:33:05.425917-0400 MyProjects[2003:1228662] decryptSubject: (null)
2021-05-15 20:33:05.426105-0400 MyProjects[2003:1228662] dataTest: {length = 3904, bytes = 0xa1377af8 bf4bb7f7 1608c50f 1355efa9 ... 5c446baf 5fe1e366 }
2021-05-15 20:33:05.426219-0400 MyProjects[2003:1228662] decryptTest: [{"position":0,"shortName":"Dan","class":"Stakeholder","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Stakeholder\/p2","project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","rank":2,"projects":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1"]},{"position":0,"shortName":"Mark","class":"Stakeholder","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Stakeholder\/p1","project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","rank":1,"projects":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1"]},{"position":0,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Implication\/p2","class":"Implication","name":"aes256 decrypt","onLeft":0},{"position":0,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Implication\/p1","class":"Implication","name":"aes256 encrypt","onLeft":1},{"position":0,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Experience\/p2","class":"Experience","name":"Trying test all options","onLeft":0},{"position":0,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Experience\/p1","class":"Experience","name":"Test Dan code","onLeft":1},{"position":0,"task":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p2","class":"Resource","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p2","project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","longDescription":"","type":"task","name":"Check StackOverflow"},{"resourceCollapsed":1,"position":0,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","dueDate":"","completed":"","type":"task","completedDate":"","resources":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p2"],"longDescription":"","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p2","class":"Task","name":"Test new libraries","calendarReference":""},{"position":1,"task":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p1","class":"Resource","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p1","project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","longDescription":"","type":"barrier","name":"Still trying fixing ASAP"},{"resourceCollapsed":1,"position":1,"project":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","dueDate":"","completed":"","type":"barrier","completedDate":"","resources":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p1"],"longDescription":"","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p1","class":"Task","name":"Without success until yet","calendarReference":""},{"tasks":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p2","x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Task\/p1"],"intentions":"Test AES 256 with help of DAN","resources":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p2","x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Resource\/p1"],"class":"Project","objectId":"x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Project\/p1","implications":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Experience\/p2","x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Experience\/p1"],"stakeholders":["x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Stakeholder\/p2","x-coredata:\/\/6ABAC2F1-A324-4CA6-8966-D410039C7626\/Stakeholder\/p1"],"date":"2021-05-14 22:16:26 +0000","name":"Test 3 AES 256","objective":"Test 3"}]
```

So any help to get the properly string from JSON data response? am I doing some wrong parsing JSON with the encrypted value?

Comment: Are you sure ```subject``` is not null? Log that as well.

Comment: Thanks @skaak, yes, if you check the logs the subject is not null, I added an update on my question, any suggest if am I doing some wrong parsing the data JSON string value?

Comment: It is terribly dense but, based on your test, I doubt the AES is the problem. It is somewhere in the decoding. Just eyeballing it shows that you should replace the *Mutable* array and dictionary with normal `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` but that should not be a problem. But do a few more tests thereabouts ... could also be the secret, you do not show how you create that in the test you edited in ...

Comment: Thanks @skaak, the secret is working fine, I'm using the md5 method as salt as show on my code, and we doesn't have problem with that because we using the same on server and client, but I will keep trying checking the decoding from JSON, maybe some problem with the string value as base64

Comment: Maybe do the test again but this time use the custom helper rather than the extension you use in the test

Comment: I tested with my CustomAESHelper and it works with the same behavior, I updated the update 1 part again, so I think you right, maybe my AES is not the problem, something strange happens when I get the string value from JSON data, I will keep trying

Comment: FWIW I can not decrypt that from the command line using md5 of the secret "dmostajo:CLIENT_VALUE" - I get "607b0fa6b0b70124aa6364aa6f72b607" as md5 but it does not work.